# NSPredicate find an array inside db

Tags: ios, nspredicate

I have the DB that contains an 
NSString *Number
NSSet *Values

I can easily get all the results based on the string Number with the following:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Number LIKE[c] %@", numberValue];
 NSArray *result = [DB MR_findAllWithPredicate:predicate inContext:_context];
```

If instead of Number I want to pass an Array of values, how can I find in db all the results that contain the given array (NSSet)?

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: ????
 NSArray *result = [DB MR_findAllWithPredicate:predicate inContext:_context];
```

**UPDATE**

Based on Igoris answer :

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@“(Values.@count == %d) AND (SUBQUERY(Values, $x, $x IN %@).@count == %d)", allValues.count, allValues, allValues.count];
```

This seem to work but it doesn t return all the values in result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `IN`:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Number IN[c] %@", numberValues];
```

Where `numberValues` is NSArray containing numbers you are looking for

**UPDATE:**

After data structure clarifications I came up with the following predicate to get objects:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@“(Values.@count == %d) AND (SUBQUERY(Values, $x, $x IN %@).@count == %d)", allValues.count, allValues, allValues.count];
```

Comment: numberValues is an NSSet. Is it ok to just add it like a string?

Comment: IN works fine with NSSets. From Apple docs: In Objective-C, you could create a IN predicate as shown in the following example:
NSPredicate *inPredicate =
            [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"attribute IN %@", aCollection];
where aCollection may be an instance of NSArray, NSSet, NSDictionary, or of any of the corresponding mutable classes.

Comment: My DB contains a class called Studends. Each Student had a Number and an NSSet of values which is another Class called Notes. I want to search all Students for  (NSSet with value 10)

Comment: i have this error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'unimplemented SQL generation for predicate : (Values IN[c]..) , where NSSet is called NSSet *Values in the example i ve posted

Comment: That is strange. Maybe CoreData adds some restrictions on predicates. Try to pass [numberValues allObjects] instead of numberValues. It will return NSArray containing all objects from NSSet

Comment: Still the same error. I did wrote   NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Values IN[c] %@", [allValues allObjects]];, where allValues is : NSSet *allValues= [NSSet setWithArray:_getArrayWithValues];

Answer (score 0):

How about ANY and NONE?

```or-tag-here
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY number == %@", numberValues];
```

Comment: Igoris response seems to be correct [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@“(Values.@count == %d) AND (SUBQUERY(Values, $x, $x IN %@).@count == %d)", allValues.count, allValues, allValues.count]; but it only returns one value as response